# Appending data from a dual loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, interpolation

I am doing an interpolation using pyresample and I have a loop like the following:

```
for l in range(len(lf[:,0,0,0])):
    for k in range(len(lf[0,:,0,0])):
        lf_nearest = pyresample.kd_tree.resample_nearest(origin_def, lf[l,k,:,:], target_def, radius_of_influence=50000, fill_value=0.5)
```

So, as you can see I calculate the "lf_nearest" for each l and each k of the original variable "lf[l,k,:,:]".
How can I append all these values from these loops, in order to have, finally, a 4D lf_nearest[l,k,:,:]?

Comment: If you initialze `lf_nearest` to the right shape, `lf_nearest[l,k,:,:] = ...` will fill in the values.

Comment: Like this for example?   lf_nearest = np.empty([0, 0, 360, 720])

Comment: You can't put anything in an array with shape (0,0,360,720)!  `lf_nearest[0,0,:,:]` will give you an indexing error.  It needs to match `lf` in shape.  Your aren't growing `lf_nearest`, you are filling in blocks of data.

Comment: `for l in range(lf.shape[0]):` and `for k in range(lf.shape[1]):` would be slightly cleaner  iteration statements.  With `numpy` we like to avoid loops, since they are slower.  But with your `kd_tree` function it might not be possible to call it with anything bigger than a 2d `lf[l,k,:,:]` array.

Comment: `lf_nearest = np.empty([len(lf[:,0,0,0]), len(lf[0,:,0,0]), len(lf[0,0,:,0]), len(lf[0,0,0,:])])`
    `for l in range(len(lf[:,0,0,0])):`
        `for k in range(len(lf[0,:,0,0])):`
            `lf_nearest = pyresample.kd_tree.resample_nearest(origin_def, lf[l,k,:,:], \
                    target_def, radius_of_influence=50000, fill_value=0.5)` did not work. Shape of lf_nearest is always 2D.

Comment: In the loop you shouldn't reassing `lf_nearest`.  You need to modify the existing array.  Use index assignment as I wrote in my first comment.  You may need to experiment in an interactive Python session with small arrays, so you get a better sense of what array `shape` is, and how to index both for getting and setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic iterative assignment in Python - demonstrated with a list:

```
In [159]: alist = [0,0,0,0,0]                                                   
In [160]: for i in range(len(alist)): 
     ...:     alist[i] = i*i 
     ...:                                                                       
In [161]: alist                                                                 
Out[161]: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Or with a 2d array:

```
In [162]: arr = np.zeros((3,2),int)                                             
In [163]: arr                                                                   
Out[163]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
In [164]: for i in range(arr.shape[0]): 
     ...:     for j in range(arr.shape[1]): 
     ...:         arr[i,j] = 10*i + j 
     ...:                                                                       
In [165]: arr                                                                   
Out[165]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [10, 11],
       [20, 21]])
```

But the preferred way is with whole-array operations, rather than iteration:

```
In [166]: np.arange(0,30,10)[:,None] + np.arange(2)                             
Out[166]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [10, 11],
       [20, 21]])
```